# Need to set default value of radio group when not checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

In my html form, I have a group of radio buttons

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="one" /> One <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="two" /> Two <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="three" /> Three <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I have a scenario where no radio button is checked. In such case, my server-side php receives input value as `false`. What I want to do is change false to `null` or `undefined`. Is that possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which server side language ur referring to ?

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="one" /> One <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="two" /> Two <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="three" /> Three <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="rad" value="null" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now if you haven't checked any radio button, you will get "null" input value, but remember `"null"` is not same as `NULL` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons, by definition, do not have a null value.

You could however add a radio button such as this:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="one" /> One <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="two" /> Two <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="three" /> Three <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="null" /> null <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And use it as the null that you need.

Answer (score 1):

That might be done with an if/else statement within the .php:

```
$radioInput = false;
if (!isset($_POST['rad'])){
    $radioInput = NULL;
}
else {
    $radioInput = $_POST['rad'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to return **null** in case if **no radio button is selected** ,on "submit" click **:**

```
var radioChecked=0;
var radios=document.getElementsByName("rad");
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
{ if(radios[i].checked){
   radioChecked=radioChecked+1;
  }  }
if(radioChecked==0)
return null;
```

Hope it solves your problem.